# Нужны ли запятые в предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

Речь идёт о море и море это Мёртвое.

Answer (score 3):

Речь идёт о море, и море это - Мёртвое. 
Это сложносочинённое предложение, поэтому перед И нужна запятая. Тире ставим на месте отсутствующей связки составного именного сказуемого НАЗЫВАЕТСЯ.